# React-Native Android Doesn't support required screen densities & sizes

Tags: android, react-native

my android app does not support a list of  devices

[image]

and the google play console shows this message

> Reasons the device is unsupported Doesn't support required screen densities & sizes: 120, small, 160, small, 240, small, 320, small, 480, small, 640, small, 120, normal, 160, normal, 240, normal, 320, normal, 480, normal, 640, normal

I have not specified any `<compatible-screens>`   in AndroidManifest file

Does dose Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue by adding `supports-screens`  to the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="false"
               
 />
```